# changing relative font size in cls file

Tags: lyx, fontsize

I am using a custom class (follow links here if needed: https://cpbl.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/ubc-thesis-under-lyx-manuscript-based-thesis-under-latex/). I don't like the relative sizes of the various headers. I've tried editing numerous things but have not been able to get a single change to take effect. For example I've changed all "Huge" to "normal". No notable change.

Edit, for example:
So in the class I found the following (also another block for bold and slanted):

```
\DeclareOption{defaultfonts}{
\renewcommand\titlepagefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\titlefont{\Large \bfseries}
\renewcommand\subtitlefont{\large \bfseries}
...
```

And changed it to variations of:

```
\DeclareOption{defaultfonts}{
\renewcommand\titlepagefont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\titlefont{\HUGE \bfseries}
\renewcommand\subtitlefont{\normal \bfseries}
...
```

edit: bump

Comment: It would be a great help for those who would like to help you if you could provide [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or any (non)working example(s) you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `ubcthesis` for thesis submission to the University of British Columbia is based on `genthesis`.

You can redefine the font commands in the preamble.

```
\renewcommand\chapterfont{\scriptsize}
\renewcommand\chaptertitlefont{\scriptsize}
```

`genthesis` uses options to define new sets of matching font commands, `ubcthesis` resets them partially.
Changing the official thesis specs provided by a university is never a good idea, though. Chances are high that they simply reject your thesis.

Comment: Great thank you! This seems to work. I am going to live dangerously.